# Force double column figure location in IEEETran

Tags: floats, ieeetran

How can I force 2 column figure location in IEEETran.
Obviously "!h" didn't work and when I tried using the "float" package's "H" mode, the figure just disappeared instead of being moved to the forced location. I don't have this issue with single column figures, though.
This is how I insert the figure:

```
\begin{figure*}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=2.0\columnwidth,clip=true]{test_figure}
  \caption{Test Figure}\label{test_figure}
\end{figure*}
```

Somebody suggested that, this is a duplicate of [Two-column figures not displaying in IEEEtran document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199180/two-column-figures-not-displaying-in-ieeetran-document-class). However, that is not my case. The aforementioned problem is related to figures no showing up at all, while my question is about forcing the location of 2 column figures. I have noted some similar questions but the solution of the ones that I spotted didn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two-column figures not displaying in IEEEtran document class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199180/two-column-figures-not-displaying-in-ieeetran-document-class)

Comment: No that is not my problem. There are some similar questions but unfortunately, the solution to none of the ones that I spotted worked for me.

Comment: In two-column documents, the one and only place in a page where LaTeX will place double-wide floats is at the *top* of the page. No exceptions -- at least not if you're using one of the standard LaTeX document classes (which includes `IEEEtran` in this case). Using `[H]` is pointless and futile; don't even try.

Comment: It isn't clear what you'd want H to do with a double column float, but certainly it is not supported. Just use `figure*`

Comment: It can be done (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page), but it would be wrong.